# Why is my Nextcord Discord Music bot not looping or queueing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, nextcord

I am Making a Music discord bot and I have been trying to make it loop and queue songs.
But when I try to queue a song it just starts playing it instead of queuing it and shows this error in the console:

```
Ignoring exception in on_wavelink_track_end Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\nextcord\client.py", line 415, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\PC Code\Python Code Files\Discord Bot\Next cord\Fish Bot Complex - NextCord.py", line 32, in on_wavelink_track_end
    next_song = vc.queue.get()   File "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\wavelink\queue.py", line 212, in get
    raise QueueEmpty("No items in the queue.") wavelink.errors.QueueEmpty: No items in the queue.
```

As well as it telling me to join the VC it's in even though I already am in the same VC [image: Discord]

Here is my code:

```
    @bot.event
    async def on_wavelink_track_end(player: wavelink.Player, track: wavelink.Track, reason):
        ctx = player.ctx
        vc: player = ctx.voice_client
    
        if vc.loop:
            return await vc.play(track)
    
        next_song = vc.queue.get()
        await vc.play(next_song)
        await ctx.send(f"Now playing: {next_song.title}")

    @bot.command(aliases=['P', 'play', 'p' ], name = 'Play', description = "Plays the music you want!")
    @commands.has_role("DJ")
    async def Play(ctx: commands.Context, *, search: wavelink.YouTubeTrack):
        await ctx.send("Attempting to play. (Note: This is a beta bot so things may not work as intended)")
        if not ctx.voice_client:
            vc: wavelink.Player = await ctx.author.voice.channel.connect(cls=wavelink.Player)
        elif not getattr(ctx.author.voice, "channel", None):
            return await ctx.send("You need to join a VC to play music.")
        else:
            vc: wavelink.Player = ctx.voice_client
    
        if vc.queue.is_empty and vc.is_playing:
            await vc.play(search)
            await ctx.send(f"Now Playing: {search.title}")
        else:
            await vc.queue.put_wait(search)
            await ctx.send(f"Added `{search.title}` to the queue")
    
        vc.ctx = ctx
        setattr(vc, "loop", False)
    
        print("Playing a song")

@bot.command(aliases=['L', 'l', 'loop' ], name = 'Loop', description = "Loops the playing music!")
@commands.has_role("DJ")
async def Loop(ctx: commands.Context):
    if not ctx.voice_client:
        return await ctx.send("You don't seen to be playing any music... (Note: This is a beta bot so things may not work as intended)")
    elif not ctx.author.voice:
        return await ctx.send("You need to join a VC to play music.")
    elif not ctx.author.voice == ctx.me.voice:
        return await ctx.send("You must be in the same VC as me.")
    else:
        vc: wavelink.Player = ctx.voice_client

    try:
        vc.loop ^= True
    except Exception:
        setattr(vc, "loop", False)

    if vc.loop:
        return await ctx.send("Loop has been Enabled.")
    else:
        return await ctx.send("Loop has been Disabled.")


@bot.command(aliases=['Q', 'q', 'queue' ], name = 'Queue', description = "Queues a song.")
@commands.has_role("DJ")
async def Queue(ctx: commands.Context):
    if not ctx.voice_client:
        return await ctx.send("You don't seen to be playing any music... (Note: This is a beta bot so things may not work as intended)")
    elif not ctx.author.voice:
        return await ctx.send("You need to join a VC to play music.")
    elif not ctx.author.voice == ctx.me.voice:
        return await ctx.send("You must be in the same VC as me.")
    else:
        vc: wavelink.Player = ctx.voice_client

    if vc.queue.is_empty:
        return await ctx.send("The queue is now empty.")

    em = nextcord.Embed(title="Queue")
    queue = vc.queue.copy()
    song_count = 0
    for song in queue:
        song_count += 1
        em.add_field(name=f"Song Number {song_count}", value=f"`{song.title}`")

    return await ctx.send(embed=em)
```

I'm not sure on what the issue is any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please try debugging the program to see where it's going wrong. One way to help with this is to create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

On your code

```
if vc.queue.is_empty and vc.is_playing:
            await vc.play(search)
            await ctx.send(f"Now Playing: {search.title}")
        else:
            await vc.queue.put_wait(search)
            await ctx.send(f"Added `{search.title}` to the queue")
```

you need to change

> if vc.queue.is_empty and vc.is_playing:

to

> if vc.queue.is_empty and not vc.is_playing:

Comment: This change has made the Bot now add the song to the queue no matter what and wont play, The Loop and Queue commands are still not working.